# MediaWiki installed with nginx reverse proxy configuration

Tags: nginx, subdomain, mediawiki, reverse-proxy, subdirectory

I would like to install MediaWiki in such a way.

1. Download and extract all the MediaWiki installation files to a location where wiki.gaobo.org nginx server block points to;
2. Set up a reverse proxy configuration in gao.bo nginx server block so that gao.bo/wiki is equivalent to wiki.gaobo.org ;
3. Launch the installation from gao.bo/wiki so that initially the server URL is gao.bo/wiki instead of wiki.gaobo.org .

Questions:

1. Is the design above implementable after all?
2. If possible, how to implement Step 2?

Comment: What exactly is your goal?

Comment: My goal is to install MediaWiki in an independent server but make it look like a subdirectory of my main domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly doable (although from a generic usability and information security point of view having different things on different domains is usually better). Probably the easiest way to do it is to not expose the MediaWiki server directly to the web, install MediaWiki under /wiki and tell it (via `$wgServer`) that it is running on gao.bo. That way the proxy does not have to deal with URL rewrites, cookie path rewrites, different domain names etc.

To set that up, you would set something like

```
location /wiki/ {
    proxy_pass http://<IP of your MediaWiki server>;
}
```

for the proxy nginx, and make sure the wiki server routes requests for `/wiki/` to the MediaWiki installation. Then you can just run the installer via the proxy, as you described, and add the IP of the proxy to [`$wgSquidServers`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSquidServers) so that MediaWiki trusts `X-Forwarded-For` headers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I am afraid it does not work in so direct a way (I tried this before). I will read your answer again later today and try it out, fixing the possibly made mistakes in my previous tries.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference (possibly just for myself in the future) this is fully possible, but a little delicate.

I'm doing it in the more general context of two separate servers, a frontend on the public internet serving, for example department.company.com, which can be serving all sorts of things (including php) and wanting to add a department.company.com/wiki/ to this frontend  which is actually a proxy_pass to an nginx on a different machine (hidden_mediawiki_server.company.com).

This is a very helpful link to start with:
https://wiki.nikhil.io/Ancient_Sysadmin_Stuff/Serving_Mediawiki_from_a_Subdirectory_with_Nginx/

On the frontend in your nginx config:

```
location ^~ /wiki {
    proxy_pass http://hidden_mediawiki_server.company.com/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header  X-Script-Name /;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Then on the hidden mediawiki server (as per the link above), nginx config:

```
server_name _;

root /var/lib/mediawiki/;
index index.php;


location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}


location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 128k;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

And very importantly in `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgServer = "https://department.company.com/"
$wgScriptPath = "/wiki";
```